# Spring security for authentication, part of role in it?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring security framework within a Spring-MVC app. I have to check in the database if the username and password match, ofcourse using spring security. On multiple sites I found the usage of roles in it. My program or database has no such attribute role in it. Can i exclude that or is it necessary to use roles when using Spring-Security. I am posting some code. Kindly have a look.

```
<authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="select username,password from users where username=?" authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, r.authority from users u, roles r where u.userid = r.userid and u.username =?" />
</authentication-provider>
```

LoginController :

```
@Controller
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public class LoginController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

User class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="registration")
public class User {
private String Username;
private String password;
}
```

Where does role come in picture in all this. P.S : The preauthorize I have added based on an example I had. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your requirements.

First of all, you are defeating the purpose of a login endpoint completely by basically saying, only an authorized user with the role 'ROLE_USER' is able to request this endpoint.

You can exclude roles but the whole basis of roles is to allow/disallow certain operations for that authorized user.

IE: A regular user shouldn't be able to delete another user.

Comment: Thank you. I am new in Spring security. So I guess I will need to create a role in the table. Where should the PreAuthorize statement come?, In the userController?

Comment: You should be able to find plenty of good examples and code bases online. Do a little research! I like to keep PreAuthorize annotations at the service layer for a number of reasons.

Comment: Ok, I will, but unfortunately right now I want to get this thing working. Should I use it with UserController for now?

Comment: @Orici It's entirely up to you. If you're doing your business logic in these controller methods, I would put it there.